# Jpa insert value from referenced table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How it is possible to insert value in column from table that referenced from another column? For example, I have two entities:

```
@Entity
class A {

  @Id
  @Column
  Long id;

  @Column
  String name;
}

@Entity
class B {

  @Id
  @Column
  Long id;

  @JoinColumn
  A a;

  @Column
  //Something @Expression("a.name")
  String aName;
}
```

In table B I have reference to table A, also it have field `aName` which must be value `name` from A table.
Does JPA have any default annotation to do this insert instead of `b.setAName(a.getName())`?

Answer (score 0):

I have to say your situation is little bit confusing. I feel some disturbance in the force if you say aName have to be name but there is no rules in DB itself. If A and B are entities which should share name, i recommend you to exclude name as new entity and join it to A and B entities via primay key (probably some generated one). Or you can use reference to A in your B and use name from there directly if B is some kind of "child" role in entity view of point...

Comment: I have a sutiation where A record can be deleted and I have to store A name in B record. Maybe JPA have some PrePersist predefined rules or something like this?

Comment: If you want to be able delete A, but let Name for B it is exactly case that Name will be in its own table. Simply said tables will be:
A,
B,
Name
where A and B have reference to Name. You should not to duplicate places with same value/meaning.